# FreeText Search Contains Keyword

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Could Anyone Explain Why below returns records..

```
Select * From CategoriesSKus where AttList Like '%|9|%'
```

But below query does not return records

```
Select * From CategoriesSKus where Contains(AttList, '"|9|"')
```

It seems like whenever i search for ONLY one digit such as 1 or 3 or 8 then contains does not WORK, however if i try 19 or 22  then works.

Why?

Thanks

Comment: likely because the numbers 0 to 10 were seen as being too common so the full text indexer is told to specifically ignore them

Comment: how can i tell FreeText not to Ignore them for AttList Column only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select * from sys.fulltext_system_stopwords
```

to see the stopwords being ignored by fulltext searches.

Documentation may be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Great, how do I tell Which FreeText Catatlog is attached to my Table or which stop-list is it using? it seems like i have multiple STOP WORD lists in my DB.

Comment: @highwingers - The fulltext catalog views, described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280702(v=sql.105).aspx), provide access to the metadata.  You'll probably want to join them to `sys.objects` to get useful object names, e.g. `select * from sys.fulltext_index_catalog_usages as u inner join sys.objects as o on u.object_id = o.object_id`.